# "pip install package" Errors with pycharm

Tags: ssl, exception, parameters, pip, certificate

I have been checking around the best solution to fix the pip package install errors :

**1. Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/certifi/**

**2. Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/certifi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping**

I have been completely frustrated after trying a lot of solutions mentioned on the Stack Overflow  and other websites, I was struggling for 2 days until I found one solution by combining multiple solutions.

conditions: Behind workplace proxy firewall

PyCharm - v2020.3 Community Edition

Python  - v3.6.8

PIP     - v21.0.1

**Solution :** create a pip.ini (did not find already generated one) and add following content in it

[global]

proxy = http://your_proxy_address:port

trusted-host = pypi.python.org

```
           pypi.org

           files.pythonhosted.org

           raw.githubusercontent.com

           github.com
```

and save it at

C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\pip

Now everything works fine for above configuration.

Now pip install  work smoothly.This is one of the solution, however if I user python 3.9.2, I cannot install **pip install p4python**, I am getting **Exception: Parameter --ssl is needed**

If someone has any solution for it please share.